# (#200) Permissions error when upload photo to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook app in PHP that upload a photo to the default photo album as a test app. Every thing is working on the test app then I created a new app on another hosting that using SSL. I copied the same code from the test app to the new app. I changed the app id and app secret in code. The problem is when I am trying to upload a photo from the new app I received (#200) Permissions error. Also when I add the app for the first time Facebook displays the following warning

"The following permissions have not been approved for use: user_photos.
If you make your app public, they will not be shown to people using your app. Submit them for review or learn more."

with the test app, Facebook does not shows me this warning.

please help

Thanks,

Haider

Answer (score 2):

New apps created on or after 4/30/2014 need to go through review for many permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review